# After moving my installation to a new computer, how can I have Ubuntu redetect sound hardware?

Tags: sound, drivers, hardware, pulseaudio

I want to move a working install of Ubuntu from one computer to another by taking the hard drive out of the first and putting it into the second.  Everything seems to work except that I have no sound at all.  Apparently when using Skype, the other person can hear me, so audio input works, but not output.  Sound was working just fine on the old computer, but after doing `lspci | grep Audio` it appears that there is different audio hardware in the new computer.

I know that Ubuntu auto-detects hardware, and my hypothesis is that I need to have it redetect audio hardware.  First of all, is this actually the case, and if so, how do I get Ubuntu to do that?

Comment: And I have tried all the simple things, like unmuting the volume in the audio mixer and in `alsamixer`.

Comment: You may be better off simply installing Ubuntu fresh on the new computer. You can copy any files you want over. You can easily install all the same packages on new system.

Answer (score 1):

Try [pavucontrol](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/pavucontrol) *while Skype is showing the problem*. It helped me solve my [Skype problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79119/why-cant-skype-hear-me) although admittedly, that was broken input, not output.

Comment: After running `pavucontrol` I see in the output tab the little bar bouncing, showing that audio is being recognized, but even with sound on full, I don't hear anything.

Comment: @dvcolgan, you probably just have the speakers plugged into the wrong jack.

Comment: Good thought, but the new computer is a laptop.

Comment: pavucontrol allows you to direct the playback to different devices per application. Try the dropdown box with a few things. My problem was that Skype hadn't selected the default input device.